# Android SQL Server Connection Error

Tags: android, eclipse, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to connect to a database on another server which is reacheable,  in fact I can connect and view the data using the Microsoft Access through an ODBC connection. However I can not do it using a very simple java code, which you can see below.

Anyway, I downloaded the SQLServer JDBC Microsoft 3.0 and I had installed in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0\sqljdbc_3.0\esn. After that I've also added to the project classpath from Eclipse with the Project open --> Project --> Properties --> Java Buid Path --> Libraries --> Add external Jars --> select the jar file "sqljdbc4" of the same path (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0\sqljdbc_3.0\esn).

However when I put in Dbugger in the line Class.forName ... Skip to} catch .. seems has a problem, and the connection "con" always is null.

12-14 19:47:38.054: E/MyActivity(13682): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
12-14 19:47:38.054: E/MyActivity(13682):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
12-14 19:47:38.054: E/MyActivity(13682):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
12-14 19:47:38.054: E/MyActivity(13682):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
12-14 19:47:38.054: E/MyActivity(13682):    at com.example.conectar.ConexionSQL.main(ConexionSQL.java:26)
12-14 19:47:38.054: E/MyActivity(13682):    at com.example.conectar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
12-14 19:47:38.054: E/MyActivity(13682):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-14 19:47:38.054: E/MyActivity(13682):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-14 19:47:38.054: E/MyActivity(13682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-14 19:47:38.054: E/MyActivity(13682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-14 19:47:38.054: E/MyActivity(13682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)

Moreover I added enviorement variables in Windows 7 32 bits in user and system.
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0\sqljdbc_3.0\esn\sqljdbc4.jar

Please, could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

```
package com.jose.sqlserver;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.sql.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Connection con = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.24:1433;" +
                   "databaseName=MisDatos;user=sa;password=1234;";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement("select top 5 * from Usuarios");
        ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
        while (rs1.next()) {

        }


    }
    catch (Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: Please see this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300711/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-via-android-test