# Cannot connect to Sql Server via Android Test

Tags: java, android, sql-server, sqlconnection, android-uiautomator

I have created simple android tests with [UiAutomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html). In these tests I want to confirm that some data were added in the database.

In my pc I can connect to the database, but in the virtual android device I get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" on path:
>   /system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/system/framework/uiautomator.jar::/data/local/tmp/Tests.jar

when loading the driver:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

How can I tell the device where to find the driver? 
Should I upload the `jdts=1.3.0.jar` somewhere in the device?

---

I have read many articles in the web were this is possible. But in my case the code is not running in an android app but runs as a test for the app. Could that be the problem?

Many SO answers suggest to implement it in an external service but I really don't want that for many reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put the driver jar on the **libs directory** inside the probject and then clean and build again 
this may help!!

**Update 1**
You can visit this answer to see how to add *.jar files inside libs using **ant**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1821912/716865

Comment: I am not building it via Eclipse. I use [ant](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#builddeploy) to create it as test jar.